# How to get enum values if enum class is parameter in method in Java?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, enums

I have multiple enums. Here is one example:

```
   public enum Telomeres {

    TELOMERE_1("TTAGGG"), TELOMERE_2("TTCAAA");

    public String telomere;

    Telomeres(String telomere){
        this.telomere = telomere;
    }

    public String getSequence() {
        return telomere;
    }
}
```

I am trying to create method (with enum parameter) that loops all values of enum class and checks if String contains at least one of these values. Unfortunately I can't get enum values to check if string contains them. Here is the code, which illustrates problem.

```
public <T extends Enum<T>> boolean hasTranscriptionStopSite(Class<T> enumData, String chromatin) {

    for(T e: enumData.values()) { // I get error here
        if(chromatin.contains(e.getSequence())){ // Also I have problems here 
            hasTranscriptionStopSite = true;
            break;
        }            
    }
    return hasTranscriptionStopSite;                
}
```

I would be very grateful for any advise how to solve this problem or for correcting my point of view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the enum values from a `Class` object, you can use [`Class.getEnumConstants()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants--).

If you want access to the `getSequence()` function. You should use a interface:

```
public interface SequenceProvider {
    String getSequence();
}

public enum Telomeres implements SequenceProvider {
    /*
    ...
    */

    @Override
    public String getSequence() {
        return telomere;
    }
}
```

and change the signature of `hasTranscriptionStopSite(Class, String)` to guarantee, that `T` extends the interface:

```
public <T extends Enum<T> & SequenceProvider> boolean hasTranscriptionStopSite(Class<T> enumData, String chromatin)
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `enumData.values()` is syntax error.

```
public <T extends Enum<T>> boolean hasTranscriptionStopSite(Class<T> enumData, String chromatin);
                                                            ^^^
```

As you can see, `enumData` is declared as `Class`. the method `values()` does not exist within a `Class` even though it's a `Class<? extends Enum<?>>`.

**Solution:**

- `Enum<T>` should have been used instead. or;
- In honor of reflection, keep `Class<T>`, but replace `enumData.values()` with `enumData.getEnumConstants()`.

Secondly, `e.getSequence()` is also syntax error.

```
for(T e: enumData.values())
    ^
```

As you can see here, `T` is a generic type which extends `Enum<T>`. You can either specify that `T` also extends `Telomeres` in the declaration of it, or cast instead:

```
if(e instanceof Telomeres)
   ((Telomeres) e).getSequence()
```

---

As a side note, from your code snippet it seems your function can be condensed within the `if()` block, and becomes:

```
for(T e : enumData.getEnumConstants()) {
    if(e instanceof Telomeres)
        if(chromatin.contains( ((Telomeres) e).getSequence()) ){
            return hasTranscriptionStopSite = true;
```

Comment: Thank you, your explanation works too and it help me to understand the principle of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using getEnumConstants. Following your example. First you are going to need an interface for the Enum if what you want is to pass different enums to the method hasTranscriptionStopSite:

```
public interface HasSequence {
    String getSequence();
}
```

The enum implements this interface:

```
public enum Telomeres implements HasSequence {

    TELOMERE_1("TTAGGG"), TELOMERE_2("TTCAAA");

    public String telomere;

    Telomeres(String telomere){
        this.telomere = telomere;
    }

    public String getSequence() {
        return telomere;
    }
}
```

Now you can both get the values from the enum and the sequence from each enum value:

```
public <T extends Enum<T> & HasSequence> boolean hasTranscriptionStopSite(Class<T> enumData, String chromatin) {

    for(T e: enumData.getEnumConstants()) { // THE ONLY CHANGE IS HERE
        if(chromatin.contains(e.getSequence())){ 
        hasTranscriptionStopSite = true;
            break;
        }            
    }
    return hasTranscriptionStopSite;                
}
```